# Warning: unnecessary check for minimum deployment target

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, suppress-warnings, ios-extensions

I have a Swift class which is linked against several targets with different deployment targets, the main project has iOS 7 minimum requirement and there is an extension with iOS 8 target.

Now when I compile project, the compiler throws warning on this line of code:

```
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) { ... }
```

"Unnecessary check for 'iOSApplicationExtension'; minimum deployment target ensures guard will always be true"

I have checked build settings options and found no switch to kill swift warnings.

I tried to define iOSApplicationExtension version target separately by this line but without success:

```
    if #available(iOS 8.0, iOSApplicationExtension 8.0, *) { ... }
```

Is there any way to suppress this annoying message?

Comment: see this link may be help with you https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15030

Comment: Most likely your minimum deployment target for the extension is iOS 8. This will mean that `#available(iOS 8.0, 0)` will always be true, i.e. it's unnecessary.

Comment: @ILikeTau app extensions only work on iOS 8+. that's why I did this.

Comment: Yes, but your deployment target is the same, so you don't need the `if`.

Comment: @ILikeTau my main app minimum req is iOS 7, extension is iOS8. both of them are using same file/class. so I have to check version for main app. can't omit it.

Comment: I'd like this fixed / addressed too. I'm running into this when using a cocoapod that supports older iOS targets than my app. Maybe file a radar?

Comment: I have the same problem using a file that is not mine (from https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire).

Answer (score 2):

Found an ugly workaround to silence warning, but I hope there is a better way:

In iOS 8+ targets build settings, I defined a precompile flag in Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - Custom Flags -> Other Swift Flags:

> -D iOS8target

Then I changed code to this way:

```
#if iOS8target
    // iOS 8+ compatible code
#else
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        // repeat iOS 8+ compatible code again!
    } else {
        // iOS 7 code
    }
#endif
```

It's not refactored and ugly, but it works!

**UPDATE:**
There is a swift compiler switch `-suppress-warnings` to omit all warnings. But it also suppress useful warnings.
Also if there is only one specific file which emits warnings, you can use `-w` flag in Building Phases pane. It will also suppress useful warnings but limited to one file.

Comment: I'd rather live with the warning :S

Answer (score 1):

The next release of Cocoapod (after 0.39.0) should have this issue addressed.  Check [this](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/871) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

> Please check your deployment target into your General and set from 9.0
>   to 7.0 or less. this warning will remove automatically.

Comment: there are different projects which use same source file. can't change it. some need to be 8+

Comment: if there are deprecated from ios8+ then you have to code for both with old and new class. there is a no option. try to set deployment target to 8.